Helmfile - Files.Get a javascript file
I am using helmfile as oppose to helm, and tried to follow this example: Kubernetes - How to define ConfigMap built using a file in a yaml? but didn't seem to work (I guess its due to me using helmfile).
I have a values file with the following, with two data objects:
configmap:
  configMapName: default-users-data-configmap
  configMapData:
    default-users-config.json: |-
      {
        "foo": "bar",
      }
    someJavaScriptFile.js: |-
      {{ .Files.Get "js/someJavaScriptFile.js" }} 

My configmap looks like this:
{{- with .Values.configmap }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .configMapName }}
data:
  {{- .configMapData | toYaml | nindent 2 }}
{{- end }}

Now what is positive is I am getting the json contents to show in configmap when I run a helmfile sync
But the issue is for the javascript contents its showing:
Data
====
someJavaScriptFile.js:
----
{{ .Files.Get "js/someJavaScriptFile.js" }}

Its not reading the contents from the javascript folder and putting it into config and can't figure out if my syntax is wrong.
my structure of directory looks like the following:
helmfile -> charts -> contains charts
helmfile -> js -> someJavaScriptFile.js
helmfile -> helmfile.yaml

The charts directory contains my generic chart with my configmap.yaml, deployment.yaml, etc I'm running the sync in the helmfile directory so assumed it would pick up that javascript, it does dump the json, so assuming its struggling with the javascript.
Any ideas where the issue is? Thanks

Any error message when you run helm template?

It is deploying the contents to configmap, so don't expect it to error when running helmfile template. As json is getting there, just the js contents is not being put into config. Although i do get an error when i ran template which is unrelated to do with this issue which is about undefined release, which needs to be fixed.

In the context of Helmfile, how does the helmfile.yaml file refer to this values file?  Inline templating won't be processed if the file isn't named *.yaml.gotmpl.  Note that the usual considerations around using the Go template engine to produce YAML apply; if the Javascript file has more than one line, for example, you'll probably need to indent it.  (I'd call .Files.Get in your chart the way you do in the answer though.)

I was able to make it work by making some changes to how you use the templates:

defaultUsersConfig is declared as a YAML object
Path of the javascript file is passed to the template, instead of its content

Example
my-helmchart/values.yaml
configmap:
  configMapName: my-configmap
  defaultUsersConfig:
    user1:
      name: John Doe
      email: john.doe@example.com
    user2:
      name: Jane Doe
      email: jane.doe@example.com
  javascriptFilePath: js/someJavaScriptFile.js

my-helmchart/js/someJavaScriptFile.js
console.log("Hello, world!");

my-helmchart/templates/configmap.yaml
{{- with .Values.configmap }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .configMapName }}
data:
  default-users-config.json: |-
{{ .defaultUsersConfig | toPrettyJson | indent 4 }}
  someJavaScriptFile.js: |-
{{ $.Files.Get .javascriptFilePath | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}

Please note that $.Files.Get .javascriptFilePath is used instead of .Files.Get .javascriptFilePath.
The $ symbol is used to refer to the root context, allowing you to access .Files.Get from within the with block.
Running helm template:
---
# Source: my-helmchart/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-configmap
data:
  default-users-config.json: |-
    {
      "user1": {
        "email": "john.doe@example.com",
        "name": "John Doe"
      },
      "user2": {
        "email": "jane.doe@example.com",
        "name": "Jane Doe"
      }
    }
  someJavaScriptFile.js: |-
    console.log("Hello, world!");


I did try this (copying same contents as above) but got, the contents below didnt come out - unsure if its due to difference in helmfile to helm:    Data
someJavaScriptFile.js:
default-users-config.json:
{
"user1": {
"email": "john.doe@example.com",
"name": "John Doe"
},
"user2": {
"email": "jane.doe@example.com",
"name": "Jane Doe"
}
}

@sam take a very good look into my code. For example, are you using the $ sign - for example {{ $.Files.Get .... }}?

Tried both with $.Files and .Files (without the dollar it fails, since i changed the formatting to look like yours), I just copied the entirety of the example you provided. Thanks

thanks @rui - i dumped that someJavaScriptFile.js in various places, one in the charts directory, one in a js directory, and other places and looks like the one in the charts directory got picked up as instead of doing js/myfile.js i just left it in the root folder and specified myfile.js. So it was predominantly my syntax and location of file was wrong. Thanks for the help, I can probably look at configuring it better now i got a base to work from. Thanks again
